# Nginx Location Rule with / or not

Tags: nginx

I've been searching on internet for few days, but i can't found a response.

In Nginx, you can use `Location` and I want that my `Location` accept my request with a "/" or not at the end of the request.

How can I do it ?

Here my file:

```
server {
    server_tokens off;
    server_name test.fr;


    include /etc/nginx/include.d/ssl-default.conf;

    location ~*test\/(.*) {
            proxy_pass http://test.fr/$1$is_args$args;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }


}
```

Thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

It is basic regex, on which you can find a great interactive tutorial here:
https://regexone.com/

So to make nginx accept a location with "/" or without one, you just need to add a question mark sign to the escaped "/" character like this:

```
location ~*test(\/)?(.*)
```

Note that the rest of your URL (the `(.*)` part) is now in a second capturing group, so you need to change your `proxy_pass` directive too:

```
proxy_pass http://test.fr/$2$is_args$args;
```

So your final config would be something like:

```
server {
    server_tokens off;
    server_name test.fr;


    include /etc/nginx/include.d/ssl-default.conf;

    location ~*test(\/)?(.*) {
            proxy_pass http://test.fr/$2$is_args$args;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }


}
```

Comment: One can use `~*test(?:\/)?(.*)` as the regex, the `?:` modifier prevents capturing, so the `(.*)` will be captured to the first variable as before.